# Re-render only a part of the panel

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

This is a simplified version of my problem.

```
<h:form id="form1">
  <a4j:commandButton value="Ok" reRender="panel_1"/>

  <a4j:outputPanel id="panel_1" layout="block" style="height:100px;border:solid 1px;">
    Content here should be reRendered

    <a4j:outputPanel id="panel_2" layout="block" style="height:50px;border:solid green;color:green;">
      Content here should not be reRendered  
    </a4j:outputPanel>

  </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

When user clicked the `<a4j:commandButton>`, the first `<a4j:outputPanel>` (panel_1) should be reRendered. But the content inside the second `<a4j:outputPanel>` should not be reRendered. 
Is this possible? (At least by changing the `<a4j:outputPanel>` to another component.)

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping the content you want to have rerendered in another panel? Like this:

```
<h:form id="form1">
  <a4j:commandButton value="Ok" reRender="panel_1_a"/>
  <a4j:outputPanel id="panel_1" layout="block" style="height:100px;border:solid 1px;">

    <a4j:outputPanel id="panel_1_a">
      Content here should be reRendered
    </arj:outputPanel>

    <a4j:outputPanel id="panel_2" layout="block" style="height:50px;border:solid green;color:green;">
      Content here should not be reRendered  
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

Alternatively you can move `panel_2` somewhere else.

Comment: Actually in my case this is not applicable. In my case when parent is reRendered it changes its style to `display:none`. Then the child also become hidden. But since the child also is reRendered, all the data user entered inside child panel are lost. I can use `a4j:support`s in all input fields to prevent this. But I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @prageeth According to how you coded your panels, it's normal that `panel_2` dissapears because your are reRendering the whole `panel_1` (including `panel_2`): if the parent component is hidden, so their children are. I think both `panel_1` and `panel_2` should be independent, I don't know any solution that fit in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve Makhiel solution by using [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_subform.html), which allows you to define subforms to wrap some content for partially validations and model update.

MyFaces also allows you to attach `<t:commandButton>` to an specific `<t:subform>` via the attribute `actionFor=""`.

You need to include tomahawk library to use its tags:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="t" uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"%>
```

Then Makhiel's code can be rewritten this way (I'm moving the button inside the `<a4j:outputPanel>` in order to put it inside the `<t:subform>` tag.

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="panel_1" layout="block" style="height:100px;border:solid 1px;">
        <t:subform id="FirstPanelForm">
            <t:commandButton value="Ok" reRender="panel_1_a" actionFor="FirstPanelForm"/>
            <a4j:outputPanel id="panel_1_a">
                Content here should be reRendered
            </a4j:outputPanel>
        </t:subform>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="panel_2" layout="block" style="height:50px;border:solid green;color:green;">
            Content here should not be reRendered  
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

I don know if this is the behaviour you are seeking. If not, just stick with the `subform` idea and try to use it in your code.